# ShellExecute параметры запуска

Tags: winapi, delphi

Давно не кодил на Delphi.
Пытаюсь запустить файл для просмотра:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'notepad', PChar('%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts'), Pchar('%WinDir%'), SW_SHOW);
```

Вроде всё сделал правильно.
Но открываеться только блокнотик (новый файл) и всё.
Намекните, что здесь не так.

Comment: За что минус? Если ни кто так и не ответил на вопрос!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение подсказал старый мой вопрос на delphikingdom

```
GetWindowsDirectory(WinPath, 255);
WinDir := StrPas(WinPath);
```

и далее

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'notepad', PChar(WinDir+'\system32\drivers\etc\hosts'), Pchar(WinDir), SW_SHOW);
```

[и вот результат:](http://freelance.ru/img/portfolio/pics/00/11/37/1128251.jpg)

Comment: ЧТД. Посмотрите ответ @KoVadim.

Answer (score 0):

А может просто нет доступа к файлу?
С другой стороны, кто обещал, что %systemroot% будет развернут? В мсдн такого не нашел.
Но и под завязку, а кто будет проверять код возврата функции? она многое может рассказать.

Comment: Ex вариант может опционально делать подстановки, а legacy конечно же этого не делает.

Answer (score -1):

Если вы запускаете файл из директории Windows, то дополнительные параметры указывать не обязательно:

```
shellexecute(Handle,'Open',Pchar('notepad.exe'),0,0,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

В остальных случаях можно поступить так (на примере с директорией Windows):

```
...
var s:string;
...
setlength(s,255);
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(handle,Pchar(s),$24,false);
s:=IncludeTrailingBackSlash(Pchar(s));
shellexecute(Handle,'Open',Pchar(s+'notepad.exe'),0,0,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: Как так не обязательно? Зачем мне запускать просто блакнотик? См. внимательнее вопрос!

Comment: SHGetSpecialFolderPath(handle,Pchar(s),$24,false) - громоздко сильно. Но сработало, если прописать естественно ещё и параметр:
    shellexecute(Handle,'Open',Pchar(s+'notepad.exe'),Pchar(s+'\system32\drivers\etc\hosts'),0,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Answer (score -3):

```
ShellExecute(
Application.Handle,
'open',
'c:\windows\notepad.exe',
'c:\file_name.txt',
nil,
SW_SHOWNORMAL
);
```

чтобы не взломали :D

```
ShellExecute(
Application.Handle,
'open',
'notepad.exe',
'c:\1.txt',
nil,
SW_SHOWNORMAL
);
```

но путь к hosts нужно прописывать полностью

Comment: А если, допустим, система установлена не на диск C, а на диск D ? То что тогда? Вот так и ломаются программы...

Comment: Такую программу ломать не будут, смысла нет)

Comment: Он имел ввиду не взлом программы, а то что она не будет просто работать в вашем варианте с абсолютным путем к host!